# border-radius.htc breaks in IE8 on specific page (works in simpler demo page)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I use [border-radius.htc](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser) to show rounded corners on versions of Internet Explorer prior to 9, which didn't support the border-radius CSS property. I follow the syntax for using it given at the linked page, and elsewhere. It works fine on this simple demo page I made: http://thomasash.philosofiles.com/uploads/examples/css/effects/rounded-corners/rounded-corners-ie-htc1.html

However, when I add it in just the same way to a more complex page - http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/ - then it works in IE6, but breaks in IE8. More specifically, it 'breaks' by not even showing the tan background-color of the div to which border-radius.htc is applied. This is despite the HTML and CSS of the rounded box section being similar to that in the test page linked above, as far as I can see. Can anyone help me figure out what's breaking it, and how to fix it?

Comment: i can't replicate it on givingwhatwecan.org so i can't help. you are throwing a ton of js errors, at least in ie8/9

Comment: albert, thanks, can I help you replicate it? When you visit http://www.givingwhatwecan.org/ in IE8, does 'Take the 10% Pledge' at the bottom right show within a small tan box with rounded borders, as it should?

Comment: @albert - see my reply above (sorry, I don't think you'll have been notified of it before because I didn't use the @ symbol)

Comment: i dont think you need the @ symbol. i just do that :). i do see what you are talking about now...why not just use the corners that you're using for the other boxes?

Comment: I could use corner images but am trying to move away from them because they're a pain, semantically ugly, and look bad on mobile browsers with images off. (I've fixed the JS errors you pointed out btw)

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as you are using a .htc file if you are calling it out in the CSS remember it has to be relative to the Page. For example:

Root of Website:
index.html
styles/style.css
styles/border-radius.htc

CSS:

```
div {
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
behavior: url("styles/border-radius.htc")
}
```

Even though with usual CSS when you fetch the URL of a background image, etc., for an .htc file it has to be relative to the document (see above).

Also remember you may have to use Shorthand for the CSS via Border Radius.

Also make sure the server you are using supports the .htc MIME-TYPE.

I would also recommend checking out CSS3PIE it has a much better Documentation/FAQ and Community to help you.

http://css3pie.com/

Thank you I hope that helped!

Comment: "remember it has to be relative to the Page" - I did do this, if you look at my CSS with Firebug or similar you'll see `.rounded-box{/*SNIP*/ behavior: url('/style/border-radius.htc');}`. "you may have to use Shorthand for the CSS via Border Radius" - not sure what you mean, bus as I say you can check my CSS. "make sure the server you are using supports the .htc MIME-TYPE" - I assume it does, as the .htc works in IE6. "I would also recommend checking out CSS3PIE" - thanks, I may do, but I'd like to get border-radius.htc working if I can.

Comment: Any more comments on this Aaron? Can you figure out why it's not working given that I've done everything you suggested?